# SR Latch settles on equilibrium state with lower voltage supply

Tags: digital-logic, analog, integrated-circuit, flipflop, circuit-design

I need to use SR latch for my design and it was working fine. Until I started it with lower voltages.

[image: SR LATCH]

CON8 and O4 are the inputs. CON9 is the output.

When I use 15V supply, it works very fine:

[image: 15V]

But when I lower the supply to 9V, I get this:

[image: 9V]

it settles on a middle point. SR Latch circuit is standard as below, nothing fancy:

[image: SR circuit]

why does this happen?

This is the zoom in of the signals:

[image: zoom in]

Output and input rises with the other input falling. Why this is happening? And why this is happening in lower supply voltages but not higher ones?

Comment: Are you getting shoot-through where both top and bottom switches are on? Run a current trace and it would show up if it's there.

Comment: What is shoot-through? And which switches? Could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Your transistors are, in effect, switches. Shoot-through is a term used to describe a high current pulse that occurs when all the switches between the positive rail and negative rail turn on for an instant due to poor switching or some devices turning on faster than the others can turn off. As I suggested, monitor the current drawn by your whole circuit. I see you have plenty of other answers below to keep you thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically build this right ?

[image]

A 2 NAND SR latch.

Note how the outputs feed back to the inputs, you have a circuit which "bites it's own tail".

Since you implemented the NAND gates using the simplest possible circuit there are certain circumstances where it will not behave in the way you expect. You would expect it to behave as a digital circuit, so Q and Qnot are either low or high.

But this circuit will not always behave like that, there's a point where it can settle "in the middle" at an output voltage of around half the supply voltage. That's what you saw with a 9 V supply.

The 15 V supply case does work because the higher supply voltage makes more current flow and this increases the gain of the circuit making it more willing to "flip" to either supply rail.

It's even more interesting to do a DC simulation on such a circuit because often the DC solution will be that both Q and Qnot will be at roughly half the supply voltage ! In the real world this will never happen, the circuit will always end up in a certain state depending on noise and the transistors not being 100% equal (even on a chip where they're supposed to be **very** equal). If you make some transistors deliberately larger than the others, you can force it into a preferred startup state.

Comment: "bites its own tail"?...LOL

Comment: Ok, so is there a way to make this latch more flippy - floppy? 
in 9 V?

Comment: Yes, add more gain by adding inverters. Feed the outputs of the NANDs to 2 inverters in series. The outputs of those inverters will now be Q and Qnot, feed these back to the NANDs inputs.

Comment: Use CD4xxxB series inverters which will tolerate 15 volts.

Comment: Yeap! Making some transistors 3x bigger worked! Thanks! To all of you.

Comment: Indeed, that also increases the gain. But there will still be a (low) supply voltage where you'd see the strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If 'SET' and 'RST' are 15 volt signals, then these mosfets are designed for a gate voltage of +2 to +10vdc, with a limit of +/- 20 vdc. Full ON voltage is +10 volts to +15 volts, so going below 10 volts on the gates takes them out of saturation and into a resistance (non-linear) much greater than zero ohms.
As the voltage lowers down to +2 volts and below the mosfets reach an OFF state with only a few uA of leakage current flowing.Such a condition would prevent it from behaving as a stable RS latch.
 To work with 5 volt and 3.3 volt logic levels you would need 'logic' mosfets for that low of a gate voltage. If you make that change Vcc can be no higher than +5 volts.